# The specified value ' 1985-02-01' does not conform to the required format, 'yyyy-MM-dd'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

So I have this date field in a model:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = " * Incorrect format or missing date")]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = " Incorrect format or missing date")]        
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = " {0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [DisplayName("D.O.B")]
    public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
```

which posts to the controller ok and stores in a session variable that ultimately posts in a database.

However I have a back button which i populate all the values  again from the session variable which is based on the above model snippet.

When i hit back i get below error in the console and the field isn't re-populated.  It is in the right format though!

```
The specified value ' 1985-02-01' does not conform to the required format, 'yyyy-MM-dd'.
```

Comment: There's an extra space in there. The `" 1985-02-01"` is not the same as `"1985-02-01"`.

Answer (score 1):

As mister [EBrown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4564272/ebrown) commented, there is a space at the start of your format string:

```
" {0:yyyy-MM-dd}"
```